# Не запускается сервер приложение Glassfish. Could not find a JVM

Tags: java, glassfish

При попытке запустить сервер приложений *Glassfish*, возникает следующая ошибка:

> Could not find a JVM.  Make sure either JAVA_HOME is set correctly in
>   your environment, AS_JAVA is set correctly in the config/asenv file,
>   or java-home is set correctly in the domain.xml configuration. Command
>   start-domain failed.

До этого момента времени все запускалось, ничего не менял.

Comment: Ээм, вам сообщение перевести?

Comment: 1. Не может найти стеклорыба джаву для запуска. 2.Почему? Либо удалили джаву с машины, либо изменили расположение JDK/JRE либо с переменными окружения JAVA_HOME и AS_JAVA что-то случилось (может компьютер перезагрузили после экспорта пути к джаве? Или под пользователем запустили, для которого переменные окружения не определены?).

Comment: Расположение переменных окружения не менял, как и физическое расположение тоже не менял, текущему пользователю переменные окружения доступны. В файле asenv.bat присутствует следующая строка:
set AS_JAVA=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91
Аналогичная есть и в asenv.config

Answer (score 4):

Вопрос решен!

1. Перейти в каталог с папкой glassfish:

   ```
   D:\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1\config
   ```
2. Найти файл `domain.xml`
3. Найти следующий раздел:

   ```
   <java-config classpath-suffix="" debug-options="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9009" java-home=" C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91" system-classpath="">
   ```
4. Убрать: `java-home=" C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91"`
5. Итог:

   ```
   <java-config classpath-suffix=""
    debug-options="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9009"
   system-classpath="">
   ```